# Change video file to youtube url

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.src = 'video.mp4';
    video.load();
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
       $("body").animate({opacity:1},800);
       video.play();
    }, false);
} else {
    $("body").animate({opacity:1},800);
```

I want to change the `video.mp4` source to a YouTube URL. It does not work when I change `video.mp4` to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vn9N8UTVM4

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the html part also please?

Comment: <video id="video" width="100%" autoplay loop muted poster="images/video-poster.jpg" src="URL">
                <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vn9N8UTVM4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>

Comment: YouTube is a proprietary service, not an HTML standard. You can't put youtube URLs into a `<video>` tag; you need to use one of youtube's embed methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a youtube link as a video file. If you are trying to manipulate a youtube video on your page then you need to look into something that's meant to work with youtube IDs. Something like this might work but it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference